# inserting CLOB to database selected from another

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have two unrelated oracle 11g database instances. I need to select a value of type CLOB from the one database and insert it to the other with python using cx_Oracle.

When I'm trying this into the one direction it ends up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Oddly when trying it in the other direction it ends up with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kglslod:subheap], [8], [0x14D9EA270], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Selecting and inserting a CLOB value within the same database is no problem.

I found out that I could fix it with a custom output handler:

```
def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.LONG_STRING, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)
```

and setting

```
db_connection.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler
```

So I wonder if this behavior is by design or what else leads to this?

---

Here some data for testing:

#### Create table and insert a row in database1

```
create table test_table_1
(
    column_1 clob
);

insert into test_table_1 (column_1) values ('test_data_1');
```

#### Create table and insert a row in database2

```
create table test_table_2
(
    column_2 clob
);

insert into test_table_2 (column_2) values ('test_data_2');
```

#### Python Script that failed for fetching one result from database1 and insert it in database2

```
import cx_Oracle


db_1 = cx_Oracle.connect(<user>, <passwd>, <host_db1>)
db_2 = cx_Oracle.connect(<user>, <passwd>, <host_db2>)

cursor_1 = db_1.cursor()
cursor_2 = db_2.cursor()

result = cursor_1.execute("select column_1 from test_table_1")
result1 = result.fetchone()

cursor_2.execute("insert into test_table_2(column_2) values (:val)", val=result1[0])
```

#### Result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00600: Interner Fehlercode, Argumente: [kglslod:subheap], [8], [0x14DF5A0B0], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

#### Result when selecting from database2 and inserting in database1

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 8, in <module>
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

#### Python script that works

```
import cx_Oracle

def OutputTypeHandler(cursor: cx_Oracle.Cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    """
    Convertes CLOB type to string on reading.
    """
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.LONG_STRING, arraysize=cursor.arraysize)

db_1 = cx_Oracle.connect(<user>, <passwd>, <host_db1>)
db_1.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler
db_2 = cx_Oracle.connect(<user>, <passwd>, <host_db2>)

cursor_1 = db_1.cursor()
cursor_2 = db_2.cursor()

result = cursor_1.execute("select column_1 from test_table_1")
result1 = result.fetchone()

cursor_2.execute("insert into test_table_2(column_2) values (:val)", val=result1[0])

db_2.commit()
```

#### Versions

- cx-Oracle       7.2.0
- oracle_instant_client 18.5 (Linux)
- python 3.6.8

Comment: Can you share a fully runnable testcase that exhibits the problem so we don't have to make guesses?  Make sure you are using a recent cx_Oracle version.  The latest is 7.2.

Comment: I've added a testcase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply pass a LOB value from one connection into another one. They are specific to a particular connection. I'll look into providing a better error message for that situation

As you noted in your own question, the first solution is to use STRING instead of CLOB by using an output type handler. That technique works with CLOB values up to 1 GB in size, but the downside is that the entire CLOB value must reside in contiguous memory.

If you need to stream the values due to very long lengths, you'll need to use something like this instead:

```
cursor_1 = db_1.cursor()
cursor_2 = db_2.cursor()

cursor_1.execute("select column_1 from test_table_1")
sourceLob, = cursor_1.fetchone()

lobVar = cursor_2.var(cx_Oracle.CLOB)
cursor_2.execute("insert into test_table_2 (column_2) values (empty_clob()) returning column_2 into :1", [lobVar])
destLob = lobVar.getvalue()

offset = 1
numBytesInChunk = 65536
while True:
    data = sourceLob.read(offset, numBytesInChunk)
    if data:
        destLob.write(data, offset)
    if len(data) < numBytesInChunk:
        break
    offset += len(data)
db_2.commit()
```

Comment: This is what I meant by "is it by design?". Is this because oracle just stores a reference to the clob storage in the table? A better error message would be indeed nice. :) It took me hours to find the problem.

Comment: The Oracle Client libraries do not support the concept, so I guess you might consider that "by design". :-)